# Cursor returns with no result after SQLite query (passes unit test but fails at run time) -- android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-cursor

i have this method:

```
public Note getNoteById(long id) {
    Cursor cursor = database.query(Config.NOTES_TABLE, Config.NOTES_COLUMNS, Config.ROW_ID+"="+id, null, null, null, Config.ROW_ID + " DESC");

    //no match found
    if(cursor.getCount() == 0)
        return null;

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Note result = new Note();
    result.setId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Config.ROW_ID)));
    result.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Config.TITLE)));
    result.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Config.TEXT)));
    result.setViewOrder(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Config.VIEW_ORDER)));
    result.setCreated(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Config.CREATED)));
    result.createTagsFromString(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Config.TAGS)));

    return result;
}
```

My problem is in the first few lines. The cursor at the beginning always returns with a count of 0 therefore making the function always returns null -- ONLY AT RUNTIME! -- i have written a test case for this method and it passes so i cant figure out why it would only fail at runtime?

heres the relevant part of the test case. i basically insert new data to the table and try to get it back by its id and compare attributes to confirm its the same:

```
@Test
public void testGetNoteByIdMatch(){
    testTable.load();

    Assert.assertEquals(0, testTable.getAllNotes().getCount());

    testTable.newEntry(note1);
    testTable.newEntry(note2);

    Cursor cursor = testTable.getAllNotes();
    Assert.assertEquals(2, testTable.getAllNotes().getCount());
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    Note result = new Note();
    result.setId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Config.ROW_ID)));
    result.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Config.TITLE)));
    result.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Config.TEXT)));

    Note checker = testTable.getNoteById(result.getId());
    Assert.assertEquals(result.getId(), checker.getId());
    Assert.assertEquals(result.getTitle(), checker.getTitle());

    //move and try another search
    cursor.moveToNext();
    result = new Note();
    result.setId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Config.ROW_ID)));
    result.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Config.TITLE)));
    result.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Config.TEXT)));

    checker = testTable.getNoteById(result.getId());
    Assert.assertEquals(result.getId(), checker.getId());
    Assert.assertEquals(result.getTitle(), checker.getTitle());

}
```

this is the table structure in the onCreate method for the database:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + Config.NOTES_TABLE + " (" +
            Config.ROW_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            Config.TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            Config.TEXT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            Config.CREATED + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            Config.VIEW_ORDER + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            Config.TAGS + " TEXT NOT NULL)"
    );

}
```

Comment: You're specifying the ROW_ID in the WHERE clause.  Are you sure that row exists in your DB?  Have you tried it with a null WHERE clause?

Comment: yep i'm sure. I've inserted the data beforehand so i know what exists before the function is called... i have traced the program in debug mode...everything works till it hits the first line in the method .... and the test case for this scenario passes ...

Comment: You're going to need to post a more complete example with at least the details of the Config contract object.  All we can do at this point is guess for you...

Comment: You can show us the database and the exact query you are firing..!!

Comment: Your test checks that the values can be read out in the same order they were inserted, but does not actually verify the data is going in as expected.  It's possible that the result and checker objects both have null values for all properties.  Have you verified that the object properties have the expected values once read out of the db?

Comment: yes i did check that the objects properties are the same, i only reduced the test case to paste here.... its a bit longer because of the property comparisons...i'm updating the question to add more info that  i can

Comment: You should be comparing the result object against the original object that was pushed in.  I.e. Assert.assertEquals(note1.getId(), checker.getId());

Comment: hey you were right, the test fails now... i guess my problem has taken on a new form now

Comment: hey thanks again @maccaroo  ..... i fixed everything up based on your hint. Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm glad to hear it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test checks that the values can be read out in the same order they were inserted, but does not actually verify the data is going in as expected. It's possible that the result and checker objects both have null values for all properties. Verify that the object properties have the expected values once read out of the db.

Comment: Added as an answer, since the solution was worked out in the question's comments.